# vba Word: Adding Selected text into right click menu or adding right clicked text into right click menu

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add Selected text into right click menu as a .caption
here is my code

```
Public Sub CreateMacro()
Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset

    Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
    With CommandBars("Text")
        Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)


        With MenuButton
            .Caption = Selection.Text




            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Test_Macro"
        End With
    End With


End Sub

Public Sub Test_Macro()
    MsgBox "I work"
    ResetRightClick
    CreateMacro
End Sub

Sub ResetRightClick()

    Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset

End Sub
```

on first attempt right click menu is displayed but empty caption, and on next times it show older caption (not current selection) until the menu item is clicked
or how to add Right clicked word into right clicked menu

Comment: This request has been cross posted on a number of forums.

Comment: Indeed, including: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?63823-vba-Word-How-to-add-selected-text-into-right-click-menu-or-add-right-clicked-word-I & http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40593-vba-word-how-add-selected-text-into.html & https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807da1d9-65ed-4f45-89f6-2b4ab18e532d/how-to-add-custom-menu-option-in-mouse-right-click-event-using-vba-word?forum=isvvba#323c6ea8-3be7-43bb-be8a-f4e64733076f. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: The CommandBars object is obsolete and is retained only for backward compatibility. Instead, look into modifying the Ribbon UI (also called Fluent UI), or adding a macro to the Quick Access Toolbar.